# wp_insert_user not creating account correctly when ID is manually set

Tags: database, users, user-meta

So, I'm trying to create a new user account with `wp_insert_user` based on credentials I receive from a Facebook user profile. I want the new user account ID to equal the Facebook account ID (ex: 1352348133).

If I set the `ID` parameter as per the [Wordpress wp_insert_user reference page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) the user account is not created in `wp_users` as I would expect, however all the relevant meta data IS inserted in the `wp_usermeta` table. If I remove the `ID` parameter from the array I pass to `wp_insert_user` it creates the new record in `wp_users` as it would normally.

I was expecting to get a return error but it actually returns the newly created user ID on success. Here is an example of the code I'm passing:

```
$insert_user = wp_insert_user(array(
    'ID'              => 1352348133,
    'user_login'      => 'jdizzle',
    'user_nicename'   => 'jdizzle',
    'user_url'        => 'https://www.facebook.com/jdizzle',
    'first_name'      => 'Jared',
    'last_name'       => 'Eitnier',
    'display_name'    => 'Jared Eitnier',
    'nickname'        => 'jdizzle',
    'user_registered' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'role'            => 'customer'
));
```

and the return value of

```
1352348133
```

I thought maybe the `auto_increment` on the `ID` field in `wp_users` might affect something but disabling that had no effect. Typecasting as an `int` had no effect. Length of the int isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with [Wordpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user), if a user ID is pass to the `wp_insert_user()` function, it will try to modify the user with that ID if exists, but a new user won't be created. You sould store the facebook ID as user_meta.

Comment: Good call, I didn't piece the two together. I added the facebook ID as user_meta instead. Thanks!